# Xcode 5.1 exception breakpoint stops in main.m

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

Is anyone else finding that Objective-C exceptions do not show the line that caused the error?  They are always stopping in main.m for me.  This used to work properly, but it seems to have broken in 5.1.  I tried deleting and re-creating the breakpoint, I set it to "on catch" instead of "on throw", no dice.

Comment: Just did a quick NSInvalidArgumentException test and it is working fine for me, assume you are just doing '+ > Add Exception Breakpoint' and leaving all the default options?

Comment: You should set it to `on throw`, not `on catch`.

Comment: Are you sure debug symbols are enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Try to expand a whole stack via button at bottom right:

[image]